# Double click not showing all the needed code for a view in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a log in view using C# in asp.net in visual studio 2013.
However, whenever I double click on the view, I am not being redirected to the source code of the view, but rather the code of the HTML where the view is located.

Moreover, whenever I enter the source code of the view by expanding my page and entering the `xxyyzz.aspx.cs` I can see only the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Shouldn't the `Login1_authentication` method also be visible?

Comment: That version doesn't exist...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Maybe he means the Community Technology Preview, which I believe people call "Visual studios 2014".

Comment: That's default behavior. Press F7 and it should take you to the source-code. However, if it's MVC then the majority of the code is in the controller.

Comment: @NathanCooper: That would make it VS 2015?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, or Visual Studio CTP. 2014 was never appended to any version of the Visual Studio title.

Comment: @EBrown: The CTP was called "Visual Studio CTP 14". The official name will be "Visual Studio 2015".

Comment: sorry guys, it was a typo, it is 2013. my sql express is 2014. I just want to do a website, not sure if I need MVC. kind of newbie in C#

Comment: @PatrickHofman No kidding? I had the CTP (edit, well CTP 5 or 6) and it was just labeled as `Visual Studio CTP` in my system. And I have 2015 and it's labeled as `Visual Studio 2015`.

Comment: @EBrown http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/06/03/first-preview-of-visual-studio-quot-14-quot-available-now.aspx

Comment: @PatrickHofman Interesting, the `"14"` may be why I never saw that number when it was installed. I assume it's a pseudonym.